# Eclipse hangs while changing properties

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am facing problem with eclipse, I have created new Android project in eclipse after that when i tried to change android project properties on that when i select Android tab eclipse get hangs for a long then loads the android packages.It happens every time when i go to project properties.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you write the exact steps ?

Comment: Thanx for u r reply.Select Project --> Right Click on it --> Select Properties --> Select Android Tab --> it hangs at this position in Windows.I dont know why it is happening please help me.